# How to add multiple e-mail recipients in a mail , but send the mail to only a selected few addresses?

Tags: c#, smtp, exchangewebservices, journaling

I am building an app for journaling purpose , were I will put all messages in an e-mail and will send it to a journaling mailbox . What I want is to display the email addresses of all the recepients of original messages in to field but not actually send them any mail. For example if a message was sent to "abc@domain.com" then on journaling I want to display "abc@domain.com " in to field of journaling mail but not actually send this mail to "abc@domain.com" I am coding this application in c#, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You might be able to edit the mail after sending to add addresses to the "To" - havent tried it, but this sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample of SMTP commands (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_vs_mail_retrieval)) that are used when sending a mail:

```
HELO relay.example.org
MAIL FROM:<bob@example.org>
RCPT TO:<alice@example.com>
RCPT TO:<theboss@example.com>
DATA
From: "Bob Example" <bob@example.org>
To: Alice Example <alice@example.com>, John Example <john@example.com>, Jane Example <jane@example.com>
Cc: theboss@example.com
Date: Tue, 15 January 2008 16:02:43 -0500
Subject: Test message

My Test message.
.
QUIT
```

The real recipients of this email are specified by the command `RCPT TO`.
Then in the `DATA` command, which contains the content of your mail and some headers such as `From`, `To`, `Subject`,...
You can specify whatever you want in those headers (including `From` and `To`).

So you put all the original recipients in the `To` header. And you add only your journaling mailbox with the `RCPT TO` command.
This will send the mail only to your journaling mail box, but all the recipients will be displayed in the `To` header of the mail when you open it.

Comment: How can I achieve this in c# ?

Comment: You have to implement your own SMTP client since the one delivered with the framework do not allow to customize the `To` header. I have done it in my previous job, it is not so difficult.

Comment: I think my problem will be resolved by implementing custom smtp protocol only . Thanks for advise